# Search Returns All Data in Database while using Laravel APi

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-api

I am working on an API with Laravel, I  want to be able to search using the API, but I am unable to
Here is my method

```
   public function searchapi()
   {

 $search = request()->get('search');

   /* $books = Book::when($search, function ($query, $search) {
       return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
   })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->simplepaginate(12); */

  $books = Book::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->Paginate(16);
  $author = Author::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->Paginate(16);
  $genre = Category::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->Paginate(16);



   return Response::json(array(
    'books' => $books, 
    'author'=>$author,
    'genre'=>$genre,
 ));


}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong as this returns all the data in the database when search using postman.

My route in api.php

```
Route::get('/search', 'BooksController@searchapi');
```

## UPDATE

I am using post man to test. I passed `Key=search` and `value=searchterm`

Comment: use `dd()` to check the `$search`

Comment: It returned null. I am using post man to test. I passed Key=search and value=searchterm

Comment: passed how? and the method to retrieve inputs from the request is `input`

Comment: what's the content-type

Comment: In the body -> form-data
In the key column, I entered a search, and in the Value column, I entered the search term, to test if its working. But this returned all data

Comment: @TsaiKoga The content type is auto

Comment: No content-type value is auto. Use `dd($request->keys())` to get all keys out.

Comment: @TsaiKoga, it returned error "Undefined variable: request

Comment: `dd(request()->keys())`

Comment: It returned [  ]

Comment: Oh! , so my problem has been from parameters I have been passing to postman.

Comment: if you are using `get`, then put them in parameters; if you are using `post`, put them in body

Comment: Thanks man, using post worked for me. I appreciate a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method:

```
public function searchapi(Request $request)
   {

 $search = request()->get('search');

   /* $books = Book::when($search, function ($query, $search) {
       return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
   })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->simplepaginate(12); */

  $books = Book::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->Paginate(16);
  $author = Author::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->Paginate(16);
  $genre = Category::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")->Paginate(16);



   return Response::json(array(
    'books' => $books, 
    'author'=>$author,
    'genre'=>$genre,
 ));


}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/search', 'BooksController@searchapi');
```